# Robocopy - multi text files -> 1

Tags: batch-file, move, robocopy

Is it possible to merge 2 text files into 1 bigger one while doing a move?  Robocopy is what I am using now but am open to other opptions.

I have a couple 'computing' servers outputting CSV-like data into individual text files.  These files are then moved to a 'loading' server that bulk imports the data into a database server.

We have a lot of small files, and there is significant improvements with lesser larger files on the db import side.

Anyone have a solution?  problems with

```
EOF's
```

or

```
\r\n's
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /f "delims==" %%i in ('dir "\\server\share\data*.txt" /b') do (type "\\server\share\%%i">>new.txt&&echo.>>new.txt)
```

the "delims==" is to grab the file name even if there are spaces, the %%i is for in a batch file, use %i at the command line. the "quotes" are for spaces in file names, the /b is for bare format to get rid of the other info, the echo. is to stop file2's first line from being concatenated onto  file1's last line. new.txt will be in the directory you run this from.

Comment: That last echo is brilliant.  Works great.  Thank you, and to all the other suggestions.  This one worked the best for my needs.

Comment: Also useful for collecting files in a directory tree (dir /b /s).

Answer (score 4):

try this (example):

```
copy /a file1.txt + file2.txt + file3.txt + file4.txt = file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for..

```
TYPE FILEA.TXT>FILEC.TXT
TYPE FILEB.TXT>>FILEC.TXT
```

Note: if you use one >, it will over-write the file each time..  If you use >> it will append.

Since you said you have a lot of little files, you can do the following as well:

```
FOR /F %%G IN ('DIR "D:\RESEARCH\Kent\*.TXT" /B') DO (TYPE "D:\RESEARCH\Kent\%%G">>D:\SOMEBIGFILE.TXT)
pause
```

Amended my answer and it works fine on a server I just checked.  One "Gotcha" is where you  have the SOMEBIGFILE.TXT - if that is in the same folder, it will add that too.  :)

Comment: Thanks, i'll try that and see how it goes.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work...

D:\Data>FOR /F %G IN ('DIR \\server\share\data\*.TXT') DO (TYPE %G 1>>output.xfer )

D:\Data>(TYPE Volume 1>>output.xfer )
The system cannot find the file specified.

D:\Data>(TYPE Volume 1>>output.xfer )
The system cannot find the file specified.

D:\Data>(TYPE Directory 1>>output.xfer )
The system cannot find the file specified.

D:\Data>(TYPE 09/17/2013 1>>output.xfer )
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

D:\Data>(TYPE 09/17/2013 1>>output.xfer )
The syntax of the command is incorrect.